# Fulltext Search with Spatial Search with pagination

Tags: postgis, postgresql

We tried to use postgresql+postgis to save our spatial data with points/lines/polygons.

Though the postgresql have a built-in full-text search engine, we have to use lucene for some reasons, and though the Lucene have a spatial engine, it does not support the line/polygon interception. :(

However we need the full-text search combined with the spatial search and do the pagination.

How do you handle this kind of problem?

Comment: Lucene/SOLR definitely supports intersects/contains type queries via the JTS extension.

Comment: @JohnBarça:Thanks, however the spatial function like `intersect,contains` are just examples, how about the spatial function not supported by lucene?